# How to intrepret this C# lambda example

Tags: c#, lambda

I am really struggling to understand what is going on with this code, what does the single line lambda return if anything ? I am unclear on what that 3rd argument is going to be ?

```
   public Task<StatusMessage> MarketSubscription(MarketSubscriptionMessage message)
    {
        int id = NextId();
        message.Id = id;
        message.Op = REQUEST_MARKET_SUBSCRIPTION;
        var newSub = new SubscriptionHandler<MarketSubscriptionMessage, ChangeMessage<MarketChange>, MarketChange>(id, message, false);

        return SendMessage(new RequestResponse(id, message, 
                            success => MarketSubscriptionHandler = newSub));
    }
```

For info the other method is

```
public RequestResponse(int id, RequestMessage request, Action<RequestResponse> onSuccess)
{
    Id = id;
    Request = request;
    OnSuccess = onSuccess;
}
```

I would be most grateful if anyone could explain how to intrepret that last complex line. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well RequestResponse :

```
public RequestResponse(int id, RequestMessage request, Act ion<RequestResponse> onSuccess)
{
    Id = id;
    Request = request;
    OnSuccess = onSuccess;
}
```

takes 3 argumenta, and ID, a message and an Action to call, presumably when some reply is received . The Action takes an argument that contains the response, an instance of RequestResponse.

The calling code sets up this callback (ACtion) here

```
new RequestResponse(id, message, 
                        success => MarketSubscriptionHandler = newSub)
```

the last argument is the Action. It is a bit odd in that it doesnt do anything with the response, nor does it run any code. It simply sets `MarketSubscriptionHandler` (presumably a class member variable) to `newSub`. newSub is

```
    var newSub = new SubscriptionHandler<MarketSubscriptionMessage, ChangeMessage<MarketChange>, MarketChange>(id, message, false);
```

My guess is that after the code you show exits another piece of code does something with MarketSubscriptionHandler

Answer (score 0):

In your example code, the 3rd argument to `SendMessage()` is an action named `onSuccess`, which appears to be a delegate that is invoked at a later time when/if the request has succeeded.

This usage of an action allows the caller of `SendMessage()` to specify any action they like which receives `RequestResponse` as an argument. A caller could specify an action to log something, execute another method, etc, or in this case, assign `newSub` as the `MarketSubscriptionHandler`.

Basically what's happening is:

1. The message is sent via `SendMessage()`
2. When response is received, `SendMessage()` checks to see if `onSuccess` should be invoked.
3. If response is deemed successful,`onSuccess` is invoked (which in this case assigns `newSub` as the `MarketSubscriptionHandler`).

Comment: Thanks for the speedy replies guys, I agree with the overall impression what the code is doing.  MarketSubscriptionHandler = newSub sets the handler that will later be called once the send is done and a response arrives. However what is the lambda returning as a 3rd parameter to the ctor ?  is it a null or is it  MarketSubscriptionHandler ? The success variable is an input surely and not used ? (typically just p in the usual lambda tutorials)

Comment: @geoffw123 if I am understanding your question, the lambda is being passed to the constructor as an `Action<RequestResponse>`, but is not actually returning anything when it is invoked, as actions are essentially delegates with a Void return type

Comment: Sorry I am being slow on this, the penny isnt dropping. For example if that 3rd param was a function call that had a return type of void, it would likely be a compile error, as a 3rd param was expected.  So why is a lambda any different ?

Comment: @geoffw123 you're passing the function definition itself into the constructor, essentially, like a function pointer. It can be assigned to a variable and invoked later, and it's the invocation that returns void.

Comment: thanks for the help with this, penny dropping slowly now. If the send message was to Australia, it might be 500 mS later when the response arrives at which point then the  MarketSubscriptionHandler = newSub line runs, to specify which handler should be called and then that specific handler can be executed.

Comment: @geoffw123 What you are passing as the 3rd argument is not the result of the action (Void), but the `Action<RequestResponse>` itself, which in this case has the value of the lambda (not to be confused with the lambda's result) and is not null. Remember that the action execution is deferred until it is invoked a later time.

Comment: @geoffw123 the `MarketSubscriptionHandler` isn't called in any of the code you're showing. All that the lambda does is assign `newSub` to a variable called `MarketSubscriptionHandler` when it is invoked. The constructor just assigns the lambda definition to `OnSuccess`. So when `OnSuccess` is invoked, you have to pass it a `RequestResponse` and it returns void at that time.